# I don't know how to deal with this kind of structure

Tags: python, pandas, structure

I have to structure data like this:

**[NEW STRUCTURE]:**

```
{name:[{base_name1:[{'date', date}, {c:s}], base_name2:[{'date', date}, {c:s}]}]}
```

I need to parse it from structure like:

**[OLD_STRUCTURE]**

```
{name: [{base: {calls: success}}]}
```

Where base is a string which contains `base_name` and `date`.
I have a sample code, but it doesn't work.

```
mp, op = {}, {}
print(b)
for name, base in summary.items():
        for b in base:
            pr = list(b.keys())[0]
            pr_date = pr[len(pr) - 10:]
            pr = pr[:-10]
            if pr_date >= start_date:
                mp.update({name: []})
                mp[name].append({pr: []})
                mp[name][pr].append({'date': pr_date}, {list(list(b.values())[0].keys())[0]: list(list(b.values())[0].values())[0]})
            else:
                print('1')
```

But it shows:

```
 TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I don't know where's the problem.

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in these two lines:

```
mp[name].append({pr: []})
mp[name][pr].append({'date': pr_date}, {list(list(b.values())[0].keys())[0]: list(list(b.values())[0].values())[0]})
```

First you set mp[name] to have two nested structures, a list containing a dictionary (pr is the index for the dictionary, the inner structure), yet you try to use pr to index the list instead of the dict.

Assuming your NEW_STRUCTURE is ... {'date': date} ... (a colon instead of a comma, so base_name1 points to a list of dictionaries).
Try:

```
mp, op = {}, {}
for name, base in summary.items():
    mp[name] = []
    for b in base:
        pr = list(b.keys())[0]
        pr_date = pr[len(pr) - 10:]
        if pr_date >= start_date:            
            mp[name].append({name:[{'date': pr_date}, b[pr]]})
        else:
            print('1')
```

And a little bit on indexing:

- [Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#lists) are indexed by a continuous integer progression always starting at 0. (if you sort the list in a different way, 0 will always point to the first item, 1 to the second... and -1 to the last)
- [Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) can be indexed by any immutable like numbers or strings, but are not store in any particular order regarding the keys. (if you sort the dictionary you need to store it as a list to keep the order, as sorting will not affect the underlying data structure)

Comment: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: Can you post sample data?

Comment: {'cadillac': [{'cadillac from 17-07-2020': {68: 0}},
  {'cadillac from 20-07-2020': {44: 0}},
  {'cadillac from 20-07-2020': {1: 0}},
  {'cadillac from от 17.07': {19: 0}},
  {'cadillac from 16.07': {6: 0}}]}

Comment: Try it now... I still don't understand how to build base_name1, and if there's only one value of call:success, why make it a dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

The object `{'cadillac': [{'cadillac from 17-07-2020': {68: 0}}, {'cadillac from 20-07-2020': {44: 0}}, {'cadillac from 20-07-2020': {1: 0}}, {'cadillac from от 17.07': {19: 0}}, {'cadillac from 16.07': {6: 0}}]}` is a dictionary with a string for a key and a list of dictionaries of dictionaries for a value.

Let's unpack:

```
>>> sample = {'cadillac': [{'cadillac from 17-07-2020': {68: 0}}, {'cadillac from 20-07-2020': {44: 0}}, {'cadillac from 20-07-2020': {1: 0}}, {'cadillac from от 17.07': {19: 0}}, {'cadillac from 16.07': {6: 0}}]}
>>> sample.keys()
dict_keys(['cadillac'])
```

The top level only has one key, `'cadillac'`.

```
>>> sample['cadillac']
[{'cadillac from 17-07-2020': {68: 0}}, {'cadillac from 20-07-2020': {44: 0}}, {'cadillac from 20-07-2020': {1: 0}}, {'cadillac from от 17.07': {19: 0}}, {'cadillac from 16.07': {6: 0}}]
```

The value is the list of dicts. **You need to index into a list using integer indices**. I think that is why your original error happened -- there's an extra layer of structure you weren't accounting for.

```
>>> sample['cadillac'][0]
{'cadillac from 17-07-2020': {68: 0}}
```

Now you need to use the key from this dict to get the values in the inner dict.

```
>>> sample['cadillac'][0]['cadillac from 17-07-2020']
{68: 0}
```

Finally, you can use the integer key to get the innermost value.

```
>>> sample['cadillac'][0]['cadillac from 17-07-2020'][68]
0
```

If you like thinking about data types, consider that if I were trying to write this in c++, I would have to declare an object that looked a whole lot like `Dict<string, List<Dict<string, Dict<int, int>>>>` (let's assume I've created Dict and List classes, for our purposes). You can see the nested structure of the data a little better this way:

```
Dict<string, 
    List<
        Dict<string,
            Dict<int, int>
        >
    >
>
```